# Error: Activity class {com.amicomponents/com.amicomponents.MainActivity} does not exist

Tags: linux, react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to build react-native project in Android studio but it fails.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4m 31s
72 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 70 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
8081
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.amicomponents/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.amicomponents/com.amicomponents.MainActivity} does not exist.